# Flask render_template after AJAX post call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, redirect

I am building a project in which I take an image from the users webcam and return it to Flask as a base64 string via an AJAX call. However I want my users to be redirected after processing the image on the server side. I have tried using render_template() but it seems that render_template doesn't get executed at all. I also tried with redirect but that too didn't work. Below is the code which I am working on.
**index.js**

```
$.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: '/upload',  
      data: {imagebase64: imagebase64data},  
  }).done(function (){  
    console.log(imagebase64data)  
  });
```

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/success')
def success():
  return render_template('success.html')

@app.route('/fail')
def success():
  return render_template('fail.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_image():
  img_ret = readb64()
  if(prev_img(img_ret)): #this function returns a boolean and based on that I have to redirect
      return redirect(url_for("success")) #this line has no effect
  else:
      return redirect(url_for("fail"))
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there any way to redirect the user on a specific condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX function hits the server, the server performs the operation, and then the server responds with the outcome of `redirect(...)`. Your AJAX call then receives that response, but doesn't do anything with it. In the first place, you probably don't want to receive the response generated by Flask's `redirect` in your AJAX call.

You have several options for what you can do to handle redirection. If you want to continue using AJAX, you'll want to return a JSON response from your /upload endpoint, containing some information usable in your AJAX request function in index.js indicating the success or failure of the upload. You can then use that information to redirect [using `window.location.replace(...)` on the client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage). For an example of this [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call).

Another option is to use an HTML form. This is straightforward to do with Flask and is also straight-forward to secure if you use a library like Flask-WTF. That will allow you to use the `redirect` functions from Flask, and make your AJAX call superfluous.